# Web service with db on AWS / lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

I am new to whole AWS world and confused with terminologies when it comes to Lambda@edge. I have simple case where web service needs to have high availability.

Website loads a JS which contains a AJAX call to web service to fetch info from database.

I could host JS file on AWS Cloudfront but I am not sure how to go about web service and db setup with AWS.

Can I host Spring Web service @Edge with db? Any reading material or videos would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is "Spring Web Service" Java?  It looks like it is.

Comment: Yeah spring is java

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run spring based services with AWS Lambda or AWS Lambda@Edge. You'll need to make sure that you package spring dependencies in your Lambda zip file

For more details about Lambda@Edge [click here](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/)
There is a nice re-invent video as well in that page

For using Spring with AWS Lambda [check this](https://www.ccampo.me/java/spring/aws/2016/11/27/spring-aws-lambda.html)

Comment: Thank you for the links they were really helpful. I went through the re-invent video but I did not see the Db replication. So when rest api is called on lambda will it always call the origin db? Or is there a way that I could replicate db on AWS regions and configure lambda to call regional db?

Comment: db response time is my concern in this setup. I am researching RDS with dynamodb to replicate dbs and somehow configure lambda to call the closest db. But unable to find any resources